# Vnc viewers fails to connect to x11vnc on Lubuntu 16.10; Authentication mechanisms requested can not be provided by the computer

Tags: lubuntu, vnc, openssl

I got a problem;

I've installed x11vnc on my Lubuntu 16.10, and I can't get the vnc to work.

The viewers says:

> Authentication mechanisms requested can not be provided by the
>   computer

The server says this;

```
25/06/2017 10:10:43 SSL: accept_openssl(OPENSSL_VNC)
25/06/2017 10:10:43 SSL: spawning helper process to handle: 47.218.224.143:1024 
25/06/2017 10:10:43 SSL: helper for peerport 1024 is pid 4215: 
25/06/2017 10:10:43 connect_tcp: trying: 127.0.0.1 20000 
25/06/2017 10:10:45 check_vnc_tls_mode: waited: 1.411393 / 1.40 input: (future) RFB Handshake 
25/06/2017 10:10:45 check_vnc_tls_mode: version: 3.8 
25/06/2017 10:10:45 SSL: accept_openssl: cookie from ssl_helper[4215] FAILED. 0 
25/06/2017 10:12:03 SSL: accept_openssl(OPENSSL_VNC) 
25/06/2017 10:12:03 SSL: spawning helper process to handle: 47.218.224.143:1254 
25/06/2017 10:12:03 SSL: helper for peerport 1254 is pid 4224: 
25/06/2017 10:12:03 connect_tcp: trying: 127.0.0.1 20000 
25/06/2017 10:12:05 check_vnc_tls_mode: waited: 1.411718 / 1.40 input: (future) RFB Handshake 
25/06/2017 10:12:05 check_vnc_tls_mode: version: 3.8 
25/06/2017 10:12:05 SSL: accept_openssl: cookie from ssl_helper[4224] FAILED. 0
```

And I have no idea why..
The software was installed via the GUI, so I'm not so used to the terminal..

Anybody else that has come across this issue?

Comment: Can you show us you x11vnc command string (e.g. `ps -ef | grep [x]11vnc`)?

Comment: Eh,  actually, as i wrote, I'm not used to the terminal and it's command.. I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: I'm showing you a command to filter + show the actual x11vnc command that's running, from the process list. This will let us see the command options that the GUI setup chose for you, including any authentication options.

Comment: Yeah, of course, how stupid of me.. this is the answer:

Comment: io@jupiter:~$ ps -ef | grep [x]11vnc
io        1658  1000  0 jun24 ?        00:00:33 x11vnc -gui tray=setpass -rfbport PROMPT -bg -o %HOME/.x11vnc.log.%VNCDISPLAY
io        1661  1655  0 jun24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/tail -f /tmp/x11vnc.tray.moW76P
io        1664  1655  0 jun24 ?        00:00:00 [x11vnc] <defunct>
io        1679  1658  0 jun24 ?        00:00:00 [x11vnc] <defunct>
io        1699  1658  0 jun24 ?        00:00:00

Comment: ... The last lines continues about 20 more times.